# Replace latex with r strings using gsub

Tags: r, string, latex

I would like to find and replace `tabular` instances by `tabularx`. I tried with `gsub` but it seems to enter me into a world of escaping pain. Following other questions and answers I find `fixed=TRUE` which is the best I so far have. The code snippet below almost works, \B is unrecognized. If I escape it twice I get \BEGIN as output!

```
texText <- '\begin{tabular}{rl}\begin{tabular}{rll}'

texText <- gsub("\begin{tabular}{rl}", "\BEGIN{tabular}{rll}", texText, fixed=TRUE)
```

I'm using BEGIN as my test to see what is happening. This is before I get to tackling the question of what goes on in the brackets {rl} {ll} {rrl} etc. Ideally I'm looking for a regex that would output:

```
\begin{tabularx}{rX}\begin{tabularx}{rlX}
```

That is the final column is replaced by X.

Comment: `'\\B'` is ``\B`` text. You can easily see that with `cat('\\B')`. **To define a literal backslash, it must be doubled**, `'\\'`. BTW, `fixed=TRUE` triggers fixed, non-regex, search and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using proper escaping:

```r
texText <- "\begin{tabular}{rl}\begin{tabular}{rll}"
output <- gsub("\begin\\{tabular\\}", "\begin{tabularx}", texText)
output

[1] "\begin{tabularx}{rl}\begin{tabularx}{rll}"
```

A literal backslash requires two backslashes, and also metacharacters such as `{` and `}` require two backslashes.

Comment: Sorry typo, it has been fixed.

Comment: Aha, great, thanks. My head has stopped escape spinning now.